# PHP how to specify ldap.conf location?

Tags: ldap, php

I have a PHP compiled with ldap support and it is working as expected. Now, I need to do some configuration for SSL/TLS but I have no ldap.conf file.

php -i says it was compiled --with-ldap=/usr so I suppose I should make the ldap.conf file in /usr, but I have no write permission there because of an architectural limitation of the device.

How can I specify the path to ldap.conf for php? Is there an php.ini setting? Maybe a parameter in command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php#36156:

> You also need to place those same settings in a file within the Apache Web user homedir called .ldaprc
> e.g.:
> cp /usr/local/openldap/etc/openldap/ldap.conf ~www/.ldaprc )

The apache web server root directory is the key here, as well as `.ldaprc`.

Also see the official [ldap man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/ldap.conf.5.html):

> Users may create an optional configuration file, ldaprc or .ldaprc, in
> their home directory which will be used to override the system-wide
> defaults file.  The file ldaprc in the current working directory is also
> used.

Comment: The provided link suggests using `TLS_REQCERT=never` which should *never* be used unless one knows _exactly_ what they are doing. I [blogged about how to implement that securely](https://andreas.heigl.org/2020/01/31/handle-self-signed-certificates-with-phps-ldap-extension/)

Answer (score 3):

Under XAMPP on Windows the ldap.conf must be either in the root of the system (c:\ldap.conf, PHP 5.3.3 if I remember correctly) or in C:\openldap\sysconf\ depending on the PHP version. It seems the path is not configurable because hardcoded in the Windows PHP DLLs.
See the comments at https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php

Comment: Amazing, thanks jayo! Was scouring the internet for the windows storage location. I ended up having to create the directory like you mentioned (`C:\openldap\sysconf\`), and everything started working perfectly. This is on IIS 10 and PHP 7.0. :)

Comment: @SteveBauman Did you have "openldap" folder already there? or did you  create both folders ("openldap" and "sysconf"). I am asking because I do not see an openldap folder anywhere on my drive and need to do something similar. PHP 5.3.28

Comment: @SteveBauman Thanks, after doing so I was able to get it to work!

Comment: Awesome, glad you're up and running! :)

Comment: @Dip I had to create both directories. They do not exist in Windows by default.

Answer (score 0):

For XAMPP on Windows, the path is C:\openldap\sysconf\ldap.conf and place these two lines in the ldap.conf file:

```
TLS_REQCERT never

TLS_CACERT {full_path_to_pem_file}\pem_file.pem
```

Restart web server and it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your solution might not be applicable as the OP noted lacks admin rights to write, that might extend to config files. How would your solution apply then>

Comment: First: Never, ever use `TLS_REQCERT never` unless you know exactly what you are doing. It will effectively allow anyone to replace the certificate and execute MITM attacks without anyone noticing it. Please have a look at [this blogpost](https://andreas.heigl.org/2020/01/31/handle-self-signed-certificates-with-phps-ldap-extension/) for better solutions