# PHP ldap_connect using ldaps to connect to Active Directory getting Unknown CA error

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, openssl, windows-server-2012

I am trying to connect to MS Active Directory using PHP 7 on a Windows 2012 server (running apache 2.4 but that should be irrelevant to the problem I am having).

I should also note that I am able to connect to AD from PHP using non-secure LDAP from the command line and the apache server.

When I execute the following PHP test file, source: http://muzso.hu/2012/04/02/php-ldap-ssl-ldaps-authentication-in-windows-running-apache, from a command line on the web server:

```
$AD_search_bind_DN = 'CN=someuser,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com';
$AD_search_bind_PW = 'secret123';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
$conn = ldap_connect('ldaps://SomeDC.example.com/') or die("Failed to connect to ldap server.");
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_bind($conn, $AD_search_bind_DN, $AD_search_bind_PW) or die("Failed to bind to ldap server: " + ldap_error($conn));
echo "Successful LDAP bind.";
```

I get the following output (I highlighted the error):

---

ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://localhost/)
ldap_init: trying %SYSCONFDIR%\ldap.conf
ldap_init: HOME env is NULL
ldap_init: trying ldaprc
ldap_init: LDAPCONF env is NULL
ldap_init: LDAPRC env is NULL
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://SomeDC.example.com/)
ldap_sasl_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP SomeDC.example.com:636
ldap_new_socket: 244
ldap_prepare_socket: 244
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying {IP Address of SomeDC Removed}:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 244 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS trace: SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
TLS certificate verification: depth: 1, err: 20, subject: /DC=com/DC=example/C
**N=Self_Named-SHA256-SubCA, issuer: /CN=ITSS-Ent-SHA256-Root**
**TLS certificate verification: Error, unable to get local issuer certificate**
**TLS trace: SSL3 alert write:fatal:unknown CA**
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in error
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in error
TLS: can't connect: error:14090086:SSL
routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate).
ldap_err2string
PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\test_bind.php on line 10

---

I have both the php_ldap and php_openssl extensions UN-commented in my php.ini file.

I have copies of the AD CA cert in DER and PEM formats but I am not sure where to place these files on my web server.  There are lots of posts related to linux OS's that simply say to place "TLS_CACERT C:\openldap\sysconf\cacert.pem" in my ldap.conf file.  I am not running openLDAP and I do not have a ldap.conf file.

I have openSSL installed but I am not entirely sure that the configuration is correct:

- The openssl.cfg file is unchanged:  http://pastebin.com/KxnWThXh
- I added an environment variable 'OpenSSL' that points to the openssl.cfg file
- When I execute 'openssl version -a' from a cmd line,  it shows: **OPENSSLDIR: /usr/local/ssl** which clearly makes no sense for windows.
  Complete output can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/h3ei3Pwp

**== EDIT 1: ========================================**

Gabriel, thanks for the suggestions / Reference.

I have now also tried these things without success:

- Created a ldap.conf and an openldap.conf file (Using many diferent formats based on various article suggestions, see the variations I've tried here: http://pastebin.com/aP94Nh4Y) in C:\ and C:\openldap\sysconf
- This article (https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/3tykpc/php_7_and_ldap/) says to create an environment variable called 'LDAPCONF' that points to the ldap.conf file (C:\openldap\sysconf\ldap.conf).  I did.  No change.
- I noticed this in the output from executing my test php script (line 2 of the output): **ldap_init: trying %SYSCONFDIR%\ldap.conf**.  The SYSCONFDIR environment variable didn't yet exist so I added that one with a value of 'C:\openldap\sysconf\'. -- no change.
- Introduced an obvious syntax error into all locations of my ldap.conf/openldap.conf files to see if I could change the test script output to know that it was at least looking at one of those files -- nothing changed.

**== EDIT 2: ========================================**

Gabriel,  thanks for the process monitor tip.  I can now at least confirm that PHP 7 is using the 'LDAPCONF' environment value path to locate and read the ldap.conf file that this ENV variable is pointing to.

It also appears that PHP 7 is not handling the 'SYSCONFDIR' environment variable correctly because it first tries to open a file in this literal path: E:\httpd\www\%SYSCONFDIR%\ldap.conf

It's still not working but now I can focus my effort in tweaking just the one file I know it is reading.

If anyone has any other tips for configuration or could share their ldap.conf file from a working windows installation I would appreciate it.

---

I am <s>now</s> **still** stuck and don't know what else to do.  Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer here should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047293/1202807

> Under XAMPP on Windows the ldap.conf must be either in the root of the
> system (c:\ldap.conf, PHP 5.3.3 if I remember correctly) or in
> C:\openldap\sysconf\ depending on the PHP version. It seems the path
> is not configurable because hardcoded in the Windows PHP DLLs. See the
> comments at https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php

So create the ldap.conf file in c:\ or C:\openldap\sysconf\ if it doesn't exist already, and put your TLS_CACERT line in it.

Comment: The comment [here](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php#116524) suggests that it might look for "openldap.conf". So try that if "ldap.conf" doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1202807/gabriel-luci -- Thanks.  I have tried these things, and more, without success. I have updated my question with the details.

Comment: Here's something I've done when I don't know where something is looking for a file: Download [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Run it (as administrator). When it starts you'll get a dialog to add filters. Add a filter for Path contains "ldap.conf". Click Add, the OK. Restart Apache (if you're using it) and then execute your PHP file. See if anything comes up in Process Monitor. If so, it should show you the path where it's looking for the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, I have spent some time to resolve it. This behaviour was OpenLDAP bug in PHP. I have reported it and it was fixed and will be released soon. See: PHP BUG #73243 (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73243)

If you need immediate fix, which is a little bit hacking, try this (on your own risk):

- use some binary editor (e.g. HexEdit) to edit php_ldap.dll
- find the expression "%SYSCONFDIR%\ldap.conf" and
- replace it with "c:\ldap_conf\ldap.conf", the new constant has to have the same length as the replaced constant
- copy the ldap configuration to new location

Hope, it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm a bit late but for me following line of code fixed the problem with the issuer certificate:

```
ldap_set_option(null, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW);
```

If you are using the ldaprecord package, you need to add `LDAP_DEFAULT_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT=LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW` to your .env-file.